# Missing macosx directory in SDL 2 repository?

Tags: xcode, mercurial, osx-lion, sdl, missing-features

I'm using OS X 10.7.5.

Just cloned the Mercurial repository from http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL and built the framework from SDL.xcodeproj with Xcode 4.6.2.

Now I need the SDLMain.m/.h/.nib files added to my project. According to README-macosx.txt, these should be under the "src/main/macosx/" directory. But all I have under "src/main/" are "android", "beos", "dummy", "psp", and "windows" folders.

I searched the entire repository for these files but couldn't locate any. Have I cloned the wrong repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that these files are no longer necessary in SDL 2.0

Comment: Any idea why this is?